# error exception handling in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is my code:

```
class personData ():
    def __init__(self, age, spouse = None, children = 0):
        self.age = age
        self.children = children
        self.spouse = spouse
        if self.spouse == None:
            del self.spouse
            print "A %s year old person" % str(self.age)    


    def marries(self, name):
        if self.spouse == None:
            self.spouse = name
        else:
            try:
                self.marries(name)
            except Exception as detail:
                print "spouse exists:", self.spouse

    def divorces(self):
       if self.spouse == None:
            raise AttributeError,  " Not married, divorce impossible"
```

### what I trying to do is:

```
def divorces(self):
 if self.spouse != None:    ##   thats mean the person has a spouse,
   self.spouse = None       ##    I think that should remove the spouse, right?
```

Here should come exception if we call divorce again, because the spouse is removed.

Let's say my:

```
person = personData(30, 'Sue')
```

`person.spouse` would be `Sue`, if I call `person.marries('Anna')` an exception is raised, now if I call `person.divorce()` it will remove the spouse (`'Sue'`). what I'm stuck at is when I call `person.divorce()` it should raise exception saying that "no spouse exist" and I'm unable to do that, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are not directly raising an exception, which is what is appropriate if raising an exception is the desired result.  (Alternatively, you could just print a message and not deal with any exceptions.)  You have no need to use `try` - `except` here.  Instead, just raise the exception, like:

```
if self.spouse == None:
    raise Exception( 'Divorce called but no spouse' )
```

Also, you'll never reach your current `try` section because `hasattr(self, 'spouse')` is always true.  Another thing is that your marriage exception is happening because of an infinite recursive call of `marries`, not because of directly raising an exception.  You should not be calling `marries` from inside of `marries`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def divorces(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'spouse'):
        self.spouse = None
```

This will always return `True`, the `spouse` attribute may be set to `None`, but it's still set. So the `else` branch where the error is printed will never be reached.

so, you'll need to change it to something like:

```
    if self.spouse == None:
        raise Exception('Not married')
```

In your `__init__` function you're doing:

```
    if self.spouse == None:
        del self.spouse
```

I would just skip this, and set `self.spouse` to `None`; This way there's no need for `getattr()`.

### Example

Since you seem to be somewhat confused about the full solution, here's the entire class:

```
class personData ():
    def __init__(self, age, spouse = None, children = 0):
        self.age = age
        self.children = children
        self.spouse = spouse

    def marries(self, name):
        # There is already a spouse, we don't do polygamy
        if self.spouse != None:
            raise AttributeError("Already married")

        # There is no spouse, so we can marry. You may kiss and a all that.
        self.spouse = name

    def divorces(self):
        # There is no spouse, so we can't divorce
        if self.spouse == None:
            raise AttributeError("Not married, divorce impossible")

        # We diverse, and reset the spouse
        self.spouse = None


person = personData(30, 'Sue')
person.divorces()
person.marries('Anna')
person.divorces()

# This gives an error
person.divorces()
```

### Bonus tip

In the `marries()` function, you're doing:

```
try:
    marries(self,name)
except Exception as detail:
    print "spouse exists:", self.spouse
```

this is incorrect. What this does, is call the function `marries()` (which doesn't exist) with the class instance `self` and `name` as parameters.

What you want to do instead, is:

```
self.marries(name)
```

This calls the function `marries()` on the class instance `self`. The `self` parameter is automagicly added by Python, you never need to add this yourself for a simple function call.

This error went unnoticed because you're catching *all* exceptions. These "Gotta catch 'em all" kind of pokemon exceptions are almost always a bad idea, because you're catching not just the error you expected, but also all the errors the *didn't* expect, such as programming errors.

(I'm also confused as to why you're using recursion here?)

Comment: person = personData(30, 'Sue'), person.spouse will return Sue, now if I change the divorces() to if self.spouse != None: self.spouse = None. now if I call it again it should raise exception that "no spouse, divorce impossible"

Comment: @user3259097 Yes, and this is, unless I am mistaken, what you should get if you follow my answer?

Comment: I did not get anything, Sue is still the spouse, divorces() did not remove Sue.

Comment: @user3259097 You need to *replace* `hasattr(self, 'spouse'):` with `self.spouse == None:`, not add it before that. If that isn't the problem, update your answer with your new code.

Comment: def divorces(self):
  if self.spouse == None:
   raise AttributeError,  " Not married, divorce impossible"
## what I trying to do is:
## def divorces(self):
##  if self.spouse != None: thats mean the person has a spouse,
##   self.spouse = None  I think that should remove the spouse, right?
##here should come exception if we call divorce again, because the
##   spouse is removed.

Comment: @user3259097 I'm not sure where you got confused, but I edited my answer with the full class

Comment: Never mind I figured it out.              
def divorces(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'spouse'):
        raise AttributeError,  " Not married, divorce impossible"
    else:
        del self.spouse

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can I delete the post?

Comment: @user3259097 If by 'the post', you mean your question (& by extension this entire thread), then no. That's not how SO works.